# $(document).ready(function() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with jQuery code inside a HTML code.

If I write the following code in my HTML code, it works perfectly (appear an alert saying "hello world"):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"> </script>
<script>
      alert("hello world");
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

But when I write the following code (with $(document).ready function) it doesn't work and I don't know why:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"> </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
alert("hello world");
});
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Could anybody tell me what's going on here?

Thanks in advance.

*edit: sorry about the missing bracket, it was just a typo*

Comment: Your second code sample is missing a closing `>` on the jquery script tag.  Have you checked your browser error console?

Comment: In both cases `jquery.js` is actually not loaded at all.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to write down the >, but it's on the code

Comment: Are you sure that jQuery is really there on your server in the same directory as the test page?

Comment: @Raulsc since you're getting only answers related to the closing bracket, you should edit your opening post with the correct code! like this, it's misleading

Comment: Nevermind, did it for you. Anyway, check that your html page and jquery.js are on the very same folder, or your code won't work, no matter how much you try

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo sorry, Now yes, it's modified on the code. However, it still doesn't work. The directory of jquery.js is the same for the two options, and in the first one it works, and in the second one not.

Comment: you wrote  "type=text/javascript" instead of type="text/javascript" --> another typo? this may be your problem

Comment: Using a debugging tool like Firebug or the Developer Tools built into Chrome or Safari, can you verify that jquery.js is actually loaded? Under the Network tab you should see a request like "GET jquery.js" with a 200 status code response.

Comment: It works fine for me in Opera, Firefox and Safari.  It might help to add a `<body>` (even if an empty one) to your HTML document, maybe the DOM ready event isn't firing in your particular browser for a document that doesn't have a `<body>`

Comment: Thanks to everybody. The code was correct, the problem was the path of jquery.js file, I used "charles" to check what was going on (as you said @dgvid and it was returning a "404 error, jquery.js is not found". I was assuming that alert("hello world") was a javascript command, but it seems that it is possible to be executed without the jquery.js file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing quotes and the closing `>` of the start tag in your script tag, which means it's broken so the script isn't loading.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"> </script>
```

---

Your edited question shows the corrected `script` tag. If it still doesn't work, then your path to the `jquery` library is probably wrong.

When coding, you should keep your browser's developer console open. It'll show errors that are happening. There's probably a *ReferenceError* stating that `$` is `undefined`.

Comment: Quotes are not required, but the closing `>` is.

Comment: @Pointy: Is `/` a valid unquoted character in all HTML specs?

Comment: yes - it just can't be whitespace. And it doesn't have to be all HTML specs; the code posted is an HTML5 doctype.

Comment: @Pointy: Well... not *"just"* whitespace is prohibited, but good to know that `/` is allowed. I wasn't able to remember.

Comment: @Pointy: Just because there's an HTML5 doctype, doesn't mean the code isn't going to run in IE6.

Comment: It will work without quotes in IE6 too. The HTML5 spec was written so that old browsers would support it unwittingly :-)

Comment: Right, got it. Just saying that HTML5 spec is irrelevant to old browsers. They allow the doctype, but clearly couldn't support the details of the spec.

Comment: @Pointy: FWIW, from [HTML 4.0.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2): *"In certain cases, authors may specify the value of an attribute without any quotation marks. The attribute value may only contain letters (a-z and A-Z), digits (0-9), hyphens (ASCII decimal 45), periods (ASCII decimal 46), underscores (ASCII decimal 95), and colons (ASCII decimal 58)."* Not saying it doesn't work in IE6/7/8, but according to the spec, it shouldn't work. Maybe I'll fire up VirtualBox and test it.

Answer (score 3):

Your missing a closing `>` in the `<script>` tag for jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"> </script>
                                              ^
 missing bracket here ------------------------|
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<script>` tag to include jQuery is malformed:

```
<script type=text/javascript src="jquery.js" </script>
```

It should look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

This is assuming that the jQuery library is in a file named "jquery.js" within the same directory as your HTML page.

Comment: quotes are not required in an HTML5 document.